# PHP Merging or Shuffling Two Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array like this

```
 Array (
     [0] => 1
     [1] => 3
     [2] => 5
     [3] => 7
     [4] => 9
 )
```

And a second array like this

```
 Array (
     [0] => 2
     [1] => 4
     [2] => 6
     [3] => 8
     [4] => 10
 )
```

And I am looking for this result

```
 Array (
     [0] => 1
     [1] => 2
     [2] => 3
     [3] => 4
     [4] => 5
     [5] => 6
     [6] => 7
     [7] => 8
     [8] => 9
     [9] => 10
 )
```

P.S.: Numbers are arbitrary, and change depending upon the user's input. Looking for something similar to array_merge, however, I am not seeking to concatenate one array after the other, rather, shuffle them one after the other.

Comment: Is the first and second arrays always have the same length?

Comment: Great question, no. They may have varying lengths depending upon the input. One array could have 8 keys, and another 6, depending upon input.

Comment: You say "shuffle" but the merged list is sorted. Do you actually wanted the merged list to be sorted?

Comment: The numbers in each array are arbitrary (as mentioned), and dependent upon user input. 1st Array could be Array([0]=>20, [1]=>50, [2]=>1) & 2nd Array([0]=>5, [1]=>15, [2]=>7). Looking for result Array([0]=>20, [1]=>5, [2]=>50, [3]=>15, [4]=>1, [5]=>7);

Comment: I'm thinking that I might have to construct a function to handle this, for example: function($array1, $array2) { var $temp; $temp = $array1[1]; $array1[1] = $array2[0]; $array1[2] = $temp; etc... something like that. dunno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
    $j = count($arr1) > count($arr2) ? count($arr1) : count($arr2);
    $arr3 = array();

    for ($i = 0;$i < $j; $i++) {

        if (array_key_exists($i, $arr1)) {
            $arr3[] = $arr1[$i];
        }

        if (array_key_exists($i, $arr2)) {
            $arr3[] = $arr2[$i];
        }

    }

    var_dump($arr3);
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated. I apologize to all if my post was a bit confusing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could do somethig like this:

```
$arrayFinal = array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB);
asort($arrayFinal);
```

Example: [Link](http://codepad.org/WNgrWTmP)

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes a simple Google search goes a long way. Take a look at the following two commands.

`array_merge()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

`sort()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

If by "shuffle" you meant randomize (even though your merged list is sorted), then...

`shuffle()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: A needless downvote with no comment? Stack overflow is about providing answers, not writing code.